# How to make Java swing Application Accessible to Orca screen reader?

Tags: java, swing, screen-readers, accessibility

I created a demo Java swing application to test that, is  Orca Screen Reader(linux) can read that application. I create a JFrame window and  Jbutton on Jframe and Implement Java Accessibility API and set accessible description to that JButton but orca screen can't read that button name. I also add tool-tip to that button but still Orca Screen Reader(Linux) can not read that tool-tip also.

I also created Jmenu bar and set all accessible properties but Still Orca Screen Reader can't read that menu also.

*sampleCode:*

```
JMenu help = new JMenu("Help");
    help.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_H);
    help.setToolTipText("Help");
    help.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleName("Help");
    help.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleDescription("Help Menubar");
```

**So, can any one please tell me that what is the proper way to create Java swing applciation accessible to Orca Screen Reader.**

Comment: Why does the text refer to `JButton` while the code snippet uses a `JMenu`?  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: means that any java swing component can't access by OrcaScreen Reader , if it is JFrame or Jbutton but the problem is the same. For test purpose I add all Swing component and implement the Java Accessibility API but the Assistive Tech like Orca Screen Reader(linux platform) can't read the components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to enable the Java Accessibility Bridge (JAB) using something like this:
  `$JAVA_HOME/bin/jabswitch -enable`

The JAB is included in Java Runtime Environments (JREs) newer than Release 7 Update 6.  If you are using an older JRE you will need to install it from here:
  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jab-2-0-2-download-354311.html

Comment: Thanks Neil for your reply, but I think JAB is for windows and I am working on linux platform(Debian), so is there any way to make Java application accessible to orca screen reader(linux based screen reader).

Comment: And there is way but I am not sure that , for making java application accessible to orca screen reader then we need to call AT-SPI 'c' library through java using JNI method, but it will works?

Comment: You're quite right @Dhairya, please ignore my answer.  It seems there's something similar for Gnome (http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/6.3/gnome/java-access-bridge.html) but I don't know enough about Orca Screen Reader.  Sorry I couldn't be more help

Comment: @Dhairya Since you mention Orca, you are probably working on GNOME; see the [Java Access Bridge](https://wiki.gnome.org/Attic/Java%20Access%20Bridge) for GNOME.

Answer (score 0):

JABG is outdated, today you need to install [Java ATK Wrapper](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/java-atk-wrapper). ATK is a project by the GNOME / Gtk team. You can install the wrapper with `sudo apt-get install libatk-wrapper-java`. Then restart your Java program and AT-SPI integration seems to work perfectly.

For Arch Linux based distributions: The package is called [java-atk-wrapper-openjdk8](https://archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/java-atk-wrapper-openjdk8/), depending on the Java version, see the "Required by" section [here](https://archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/java-atk-wrapper-common/). Not sure why there is no `java-atk-wrapper-openjdk18` though or how to get it to work with Java 18, but at least you can switch Java versions with `archlinux-java` command.

(taken from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1439156/378854))